# How can i get child inside child inside child value without know the inside child and set recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase

IN FIREBASE DATABASE

Cart:  THIS child ONLY I KNOW

Cart:

```
12345   USER ID

  22222    TIMESTAMP ID
    0
    "Itemname " : "Apple"
    1
    "Itemname " : "Iphone"



"22345"         user id
  "11111"          timestamp id
     0
    "Itemname " : "Pin"
     1      
    "Itemname " : "Volleyball "
  } 
}
```

}
}
I need to retrieve Itemname value and set recyclerview in Androidstudio, how can I retrieve this value..

"Cart:" : {

```
"12345" : {

  "22222" : [ {

    "Itemname " : "Apple"

  }, {
    "Itemname " : "Iphone"
  } ]
},
"22345" : {

  "11111" : [ {

    "Itemname " : "Pin"
  }, {
    "Itemname " : "Volleyball "
  } ]
}
```

}
}

I

Comment: I cannot see any `Cart` in your schema. Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I added my json

Comment: So you want to display a list containing "Apple", "Iphone", "Pin" and "Volleyball". Have you tried something so far?

Comment: Yes , implement nested recyclerview,  firebase recycler adapter and I successfully get user id inside child recyclerview I need to show Itemname, in this childholder, iam confused. How can I pass userid from parent recycler adapter to child recyclerview..